# how to search in array and return all values or keys of element that contains the value searched for

Tags: javascript

I want to create a function that returns all the values that contains the value searched for.

---

for example:
I have an array of these values: "red", "green", "blue"

---

if I searched for "re" the result would be: "red", "green" or the keys 0, 1

Answer (score 3):

```
["red","green","blue"].filter( RegExp.prototype.test.bind( /re/ ) );

//["red", "green"]
```

[Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
[Function#bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: +1, you _just_ beat me with the same answer. Nice use of `.bind()`, noting though for @Sami Al-Subhi that `.filter()` and `bind()` aren't supported by IE < 9, but the MDN links in the answer tell you what to do about that.

Comment: Or maybe this... `["red","green","blue"].filter( /./.test.bind( /re/ ) );`

Answer (score 1):

You should iterate over the array using a [`for` loop](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=mdc%20for%20loop&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for&ei=bVj0TrTCNsiD8gPclfi8AQ&usg=AFQjCNFDqQ037gdKIez3uINJAI0HMxbv0Q), do a [`String.search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) on each item, and hold an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) of matches.